# Writing if then else in Linq to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, if-statement, linq-to-entities

I wrote following code to count refers to a `Document` to:

```
var currentStationId = GetCurrentStation();
var result = dbContext
            .Documents
            .Select(x=> 
                    new MyDTO{
                            ...,
                            ReferCounts = x.DocumentStationHistories
                                           .Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId))
                             }
```

Now I want to change mechanism of calculating `ReferCounts`:

```
if(currentStationId == 1) ReferCounts = x.DocumentStationHistories
                                         .Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId &&
                                                     t.FromStationId != t.ToStationId))
else
    ReferCounts = x.DocumentStationHistories
                   .Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId))
```

How can I use this code in my linq to entities query?

Comment: what about the [ternary if](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) syntax?

Comment: Change format : (currentStationId == 1) ? ReferCounts = x.DocumentStationHistories
                                         .Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId &&
                                                     t.FromStationId != t.ToStationId))
:
    ReferCounts = x.DocumentStationHistories
                   .Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the [ternary if](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) syntax.

```
var result = dbContext
        .Documents
        .Select(x=> 
                new MyDTO{
                        ...,
                        ReferCounts = (currentStationId == 1) ?
                             x.DocumentStationHistories.Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId && t.FromStationId != t.ToStationId)) 
                           : x.DocumentStationHistories.Count(t => t.ToStationId == currentStationId))
                         }
```